# Writing formula field1 equals=true OR field2 is not equal

Tags: formula, formula-field

I am trying to create a workflow rule that will evaluated two fields. A boolean  field if it is equal to true, and a text field which is not empty

How can I accomplish the following in the formula:

```
if (field1__c equals = true) || field2__c is not empty) {
   return true
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use the `OR()` function in combination with the `NOT()` and `ISBLANK()` functions to achieve something like this:

```
OR(Field1__c, NOT(ISBLANK(Field2__c)))
```

A full list of formula functions can be found [in the salesforce help here](https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewHelpDoc?id=customize_functions.htm)

Answer (score 2):

`field1__c || !ISBLANK(field2__c)`
or
`OR(field1__c, NOT(ISBLANK(field2__c)))`

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like

```
 And(field__c==true ,  !ISBLANK(field2__c) )
```

Comment: `field1__c ` is boolean

Comment: From your description it is not clear if you require an AND or OR operator, any way the logic should remain the same regardless